# PHP SQL Query while loop query only shows only first value for all columns

Tags: php

```
<?php
  require 'db.inc.php';
  $Name = $_POST['Name'];
  $NewHighScore = $_POST['HighScore'];
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM CovidShooter;";
  $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
  if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
      header("Location: index.php?error0=sqlerror");
      exit();
  }
  else {
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
      $n = 0;
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $HighScore.$n = $row['highscore'];
        $Rank.$n = $row['Rank'];
        echo $Rank.$n;
        echo $HighScore.$n;
        $n++; 
        }
    }
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

  mysqli_close($conn);
```

If I put the echo statment between $Highscore and $Rank both values show. However when I put the $Highscore right in front of the $Rank it will show the highscore value for both $Rank & $Highscore. When I switch the the order it will only show Rank value for $Rank & $Highscore. Why is that? Am I doing something wrong or maybe I am ignorant of a rule set with SQL. I dont know. Please provide insight if you have any. Thank you,

Comment: $HighScore.$n = $row['highscore']; makes no sense. you are probably confusing PHP syntax with something else

Comment: What do you mean that makes no sense? It is incrementing High Score through each loop. It seems to work just fine when I echo the statements.

Comment: Is there a better way to accomplish incrementing the variable? Or should I just use an array? I probably should put it an array but I am lazy.... lol

Comment: What you want, is called variable variables, https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php - and yes, you _should_ be using an array instead. "Numbered" variable names are not good style.

Comment: Why vote my post down? It is a valid question. Such a toxic community.

Comment: This looks like a use case for an array rather than lots of numbered variables.

Comment: P.s. any votes you may receive are a judgement of the question, not the questioner...people seem very ready to take everything personally or think every click is part of some wider culture war / conspiracy to beat other people down. If you hover your mouse over the button you can why down votes are actually given. There's also an article in the help centre about it

Comment: Thing is I did a lot of research on the topic and have used numbered variables before. I know I could of thrown it in an array. I just wanted to understand why it didn't work. I couldn't find an answer so I asked the stack overflow community.

Comment: When I put it in an array it echo's just fine no matter the order. It is interesting how it changes based off being an array compared to an incremented variable.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of thing arrays are designed for, that's why :-)

Comment: Anyway obviously I don't know _exactly_ why you got downvoted (it wasn't me, and you can't see who it was or the precise reason), but perhaps they felt the question was a bit unclear - there's a fairly dense, unformatted explanation without a specific example...it's not the most readable. That's just my guess, although it's still a harsh-ish downvote, in that case. But please forgive me for suggesting that, IMHO, to label the entire community as "toxic" just because you received _one_ anonymous downvote is possibly a bit of a leap of the imagination... :-)

Comment: Yea I know most are helpful. I shouldn't of grouped in the whole community from the feedback from one individual. We do not need more of that in society. To say the least.

Answer (score 0):

You have to submit them after the cycle

```
while ( __SOMETHING $y__ ) {
  $x .= $y;
}

echo $x;
```